# How to flip a moving image horizontally when it reaches a certain point on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, flip

**Overview**

For my school project I have to create an animation in HTML, CSS and Javascript. I have just started to learn how to code and so am new to these kinds of projects. I have been able to make an image of mario move across the screen and then move back, but I want the image to flip when it reaches the start and end of the container. I have no idea how to do this and would be so grateful if someone could help me.

```js
var objX = 0;
var change = 10;

function moveBlock() {
  var obj = document.getElementById("object");
  if ((objX + 251) > 1100) {
    change = -10;

  } else if (objX == 0) {
    change = 10;
  }
  objX = objX + change;
  obj.style.left = objX + "px";
}
```

```css
.rotate {
  animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

#grass {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}

#container {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

#object {
  width: 251px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Hib.png")
}
```

```html
<h1>Layers and animation</h1>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
<div id="container">
  <div id="object"></div>
</div>
<div id="grass"></div>
<br/>
<button onclick="setInterval(moveBlock, 25)">Click Me</button>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Hib.png

Comment: Your snippet seems to be rotating several images but not moving them, whereas the text in your question talks of Mario moving and needing to flip him when he gets to the end. Could you explain a bit more what you want?

Comment: The image with the id of "object" is a picture of Mario. He moves across the screen up until the end of the container and then moves back again, this looks like he is walking backwards and I would like the image to flip so that it looks like he is always moving forwards.

Comment: Your snippet still just shows rotating heads - and a container at the bottom which is green. I can see that is where Mario is supposed to be but your snippet is not working because you have not loaded an image of Mario that we can see. Please put one up. You can load it using the picture icon in the editor, get the url on imgur from that and paste it into your snippet. Please then check that your snippet is working here on SO, not just on your local system, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following snippet can be of help, please do not hesitate to ask if there is any doubt.

```js
const img = document.getElementById('img');
const container = img.parentElement;

let left = 0;
let sign = 1;

let ticking = false;

img.style.left = `${left}px`;
img.style.transform = `scaleX(${sign})`;

function translate() {
  // YOU CAN CHANGE THE SPEED BY CHANGING THIS.
  left += sign * 10;
    
  if (left + img.offsetWidth >= container.clientWidth) {
    // CASE: RIGHT LIMIT.
    left = container.clientWidth - img.offsetWidth;
    sign *= -1;
  } else if (left <= 0) {
    // CASE: LEFT LIMIT.
    left = 0;
    sign *= -1;
  }
    
  if (ticking) {
    return;
  }
  
  // THIS WILL RUN THE CALLBACK WHEN THE BROWSER IS READY TO DO A REPAINT. (JUST A PERFORMANCE IMPROVEMENT)
  requestAnimationFrame(() => { 
    img.style.left = `${left}px`;
    img.style.transform = `scaleX(${sign})`;
    
    ticking = false;
  });
  
  ticking = true;
}

setInterval(translate, 10);
```

```css
#img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<img id='img' src='https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png' />
```

Comment: How would you change this code to attach it to the mario image (with the Id "object") so that mario flips?

Comment: @Hannah you just have to change `document.getElementById('img')` with `document.getElementById('object')`. Is that what you are asking?